# Remove duplicates taking into account two columns, lower case and accents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

| code | town | district | suburb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | Benalmádena | Málaga | Arroyo de la Miel |
| 03 | Alicante | Jacarilla | Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla) |
| 04 | Cabrera d'Anoia | Barcelona | Cabrera D'Anoia |
| 07 | Lanjarón | Granada | Lanjaron |
| 08 | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Centro-Ifara |
| 09 | Córdoba | Córdoba | Cordoba |

For each row in the `suburb` column, if the value it contains is equal (in lower case and without accents) to `district` or `town` columns, it becomes NaN.

```
# Function to remove accents and shift to lower case.
def rm_accents_lowcase(a):
    return unidecode.unidecode(a).lower()
```

Example:

| code | town | district | suburb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | Benalmádena | Málaga | Arroyo de la Miel |
| 03 | Alicante | Jacarilla | Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla) |
| 04 | Cabrera d'Anoia | Barcelona | NaN |
| 07 | Lanjarón | Granada | NaN |
| 08 | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Santa Cruz de Tenerife | Centro-Ifara |
| 09 | Córdoba | Córdoba | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function and check each row of pandas with a written function and `apply`, `axis=1`.

```
# !pip install unidecode
import numpy as np
import unidecode

def check_unidecode(row):
    lst = [unidecode.unidecode(r).lower() for r in row]
    # If we suppose that we want to check value of last column with other values of other columns in each row
    if lst[-1] in lst[:-1]:
        return np.nan
    return row['suburb']
df['suburb'] = df.apply(check_unidecode, axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
                     town                district  \
0             Benalmádena                  Málaga   
1                Alicante               Jacarilla   
2         Cabrera d'Anoia               Barcelona   
3                Lanjarón                 Granada   
4  Santa Cruz de Tenerife  Santa Cruz de Tenerife   
5                 Córdoba                 Córdoba   

                                    suburb  
0                        Arroyo de la Miel  
1  Jacarilla, Correntias Bajas (Jacarilla)  
2                                      NaN  
3                                      NaN  
4                             Centro-Ifara  
5                                      NaN
```

**Update** If you want to check the specific column with any order with other columns you can try like below:

```
col_chk = 'suburb'
def check_unidecode(row):
    lst = []
    for col_name, val in zip(row.index, row):
        tmp = unidecode.unidecode(val).lower()
        if col_name != col_chk:
            lst.append(tmp)
        else:
            val_chk = tmp
    if val_chk in lst:
        return np.nan
    return row[col_chk]
df[col_chk] = df.apply(check_unidecode, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: If there were more columns in the DataFrame or if they were in a different order, your code would not work.

Comment: @Carola, edited answer, With this approach we can check with any numbers of columns

Comment: I think it should be independent of the column position, your solution should only take into account the column name.

Comment: @Carola, I will send and answer for solving without ordering

Comment: @Carola, edited answer, see update part

Answer (score 1):

You can remove accents and make lower with this code

```
df['suburb'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower()
```

```
df['check'] = np.where(
    ((df['suburb'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower() == df['town'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower())
    |  (df['suburb'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower() == df['district'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.lower())
    ),
    np.nan, df['suburb']) 
df
```

[image]

Comment: Can you think of a version with less duplicated code?

Comment: I will try to write a def function so it will be better